# Merge by a condition

Tags: r, database, for-loop, bioinformatics

I have this two db:

```
dfgenus<- c("Coragyps" ,"Elanus", "Elanus", "Patagioenas", "Crotophaga")
```

so

```
dfgenus
       Genus
1     Coragyps
2       Elanus
3       Elanus
4  Patagioenas
5   Crotophaga
```

and

```
family <-c("Cathartidae", "Accipitridae","Cuculidae", "Columbidae","Psittacidae")
Genus <- c("Coragyps" ,"Elanus", "Crotophaga", "Patagioenas", "Pyrrhura")

sacc<- data.frame(family, genus)
##Sacc db rows are in the right order (the genus belongs to its taxonomic family)

sacc
  family       Genus
1  Cathartidae    Coragyps
2 Accipitridae      Elanus
3    Cuculidae  Crotophaga
4   Columbidae Patagioenas
5  Psittacidae    Pyrrhura
```

following the info on "sacc", how can I add the correct family for each genus in "dbgenus"?

I've been unsuccesfully trying:

```
for (i in length(dfgenus)){
if (identical(sacc[i], dfgenus[i])) {
    df$family[i] <- sacc$family[i] 
}   else {
        i-1 
} 
print(df$family) 
}
```

the output should be:

```
df
        family       Genus
1  Cathartidae    Coragyps
2 Accipitridae      Elanus
3 Accipitridae      Elanus
4   Columbidae Patagioenas
5    Cuculidae  Crotophaga
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

dbgenus<- data.frame(genus = c("Coragyps" ,"Elanus", "Elanus", "Patagioenas", "Crotophaga"))
family <-c("Cathartidae", "Accipitridae","Cuculidae", "Columbidae","Psittacidae")
genus <- c("Coragyps" ,"Elanus", "Crotophaga", "Patagioenas", "Pyrrhura")

sacc<- data.frame(family, genus)

dbgenus %>% left_join(sacc)
```

Comment: This works but consider `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating data frames (or use tibbles) to avoid the warning about factor levels.

Comment: I recommend setting this to FALSE as default using options.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for this, i've had been stuck on that for a long time :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve your result. None of them should involve for-loops :)

If you made `dfgenus` a data frame (with one column), you could investigate the `merge()` function, or a join function from the `dplyr` package.

But using your data as it stands, you can use `match()`:

```
newdf <- data.frame(Genus  = dfgenus, 
                    Family = sacc[match(dfgenus, sacc$Genus), "family"])

        Genus       Family
1    Coragyps  Cathartidae
2      Elanus Accipitridae
3      Elanus Accipitridae
4 Patagioenas   Columbidae
5  Crotophaga    Cuculidae
```

`match` returns the matching row numbers from `sacc`, which are then used to return the subset from the `family` column.